# Activity Not opening on Button click events

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I have created an android application.
I have created 2 Activities.First is MainActivity and the other is Registration.
I  have added one Button in my  MainActivity.
Onclick listener is working fine with the first activity.But when m on my second activity  that is Registration, no operations are working,.

NOTE :-
1.I am using latest SDK
2.I have used the corrert way of creating onclick listener events.
3.I m able to go to second activity,but not able to come from Registration to MainActivity  activity.

Comment: Its impossible to say without seeing your code that isn't working. Also, are you getting any errors or it simply does nothing?

Comment: Right now m using mobile.so sorry i cant upload the code. I will upload within 20 min

Comment: Are you calling finish() in the main activity after starting the second activity? This removes it from the backstack and so you can't go back to it. You can always set android:parentActivityName="" in the manifest so the context "up" in the action bar will return, reopening the original activity, even if it's closed

Comment: I am jus simple using setcontentview(r.layout.activity_main) on my button click listener

Answer (score 0):

> I am jus simple using setcontentview(r.layout.activity_main) on my button click listener

It would still be helpful to see your code but from that comment I can tell you that you should probably be doing it differently. You don't typically want to do this and this is not how to change `Activities`. You need to have separate java files for each `Activity` as well as separate xml (layout) files which it sounds like you have that.

To switch `Activities` you should be using an `Intent` like in your `MainActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

then in your `onClick()` in `RegistrationActivity` you should have something like

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This would create a new instance of `MainActivity` if it is destroyed. If you don't call `finish()` on your `MainActivity` and you don't need a new instance then you can simply call `finish()` in your `onClick()` of `RegistrationActivity`

Comment: Thanks. But m able to performing all operations on my first MainActivity.Like Toast.,AlertDialog, intent.But not able to performing same operation on clicked Registration.java activity.

Comment: Ok, well will wait until you post code. Do you have two separate java files for each `Activity`?